# bootgrid not showing data

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am using `Jquery` `bootgrid` plugin on button click i am initializing the plugin but when the plugin is initialized the data is lost although i says showing 1-78 records but no record is visible i checked through chrome developer tools but no data is present
table is generated from `gridview` of `asp.net` `webforms`

plugin url: http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/

JS CODE

```
function testBtn() {
            $("table.rt").bootgrid();
        }
```

HTML CODE

```
 <button id="init-basic" type="button" 
class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="testBtn();">
                            Prettify Table</button>
```

[image]

Comment: If your question is still unresolved could you please add some HTML code of the your table creation? I don't know how is `gridview` works and what html code it leaves after the table body generation. As I know jquery-bootgrid needs simple tr, td tags inside the table body as we can see in the Basic Example, or it makes the ajax request as we can see in the Data Example.

Comment: try adding <thead> and <tbody> tags

Answer (score 1):

Check the following in your html, I had strange results without these tags:

- Ensure you have one column specified as: data-identifier="true"
- Ensure all columns have a data id attribute: data-column-id="GroupID"

See below an extract from my working table:

```
    <thead>
        <tr class="active">
            <th data-column-id="GroupID" data-identifier="true" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
            <th data-column-id="GroupName" data-order="asc">Name</th>
            <th data-column-id="GroupDesc">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; it turns out I hadn't included the `<thead>` tags - as suggested above.

```
<table id="tradeBook" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-column-id="index" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">Index</th>
```