# How to "enable" the jquery bootgrid grid/table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to incorporate a grid/table in my html5 page populated with data from sql server using razor.  I am a complete and absolute newbie.  My page works and the SQL query works.  Last thing I need is to get the table to look and behave like the basic bootgrid example here:  http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples#basic

I've done the following:

- Created a new cshtml page/site and installed Bootstrap, jquery and the jquery bootgrid using the Nuget package manager.
- Added references to these js and css files from html page's head section.
- Created a html table and populated with data from SQL Server
- Formatted the table using bootstrap.  Up to here, everything works.

Now I cannot get any of bootgrid look and feel to activate.  I've gone through the "documentation" page on the bootgrid website and even copied one of the samples off their site but nothing works.

On stackoverflow, I did a search and found the following three posts that kind of relates to my problem but didn't lead me to any solutions.

- [Display datatable at view with possibility of edit/add elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875020/display-datatable-at-view-with-possibility-of-edit-add-elements/29875697#29875697)
- [Best Datagrid for Bootstrap/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711201/best-datagrid-for-bootstrap-jquery)
- [bootgrid not showing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214933/bootgrid-not-showing-data)

I must be missing some step or something that activates the bootgrid functionality.

Here is my basic CSHTML page I'm using to test/learn bootgrid:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>My Site's Title</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery.bootgrid.min.css">
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.bootgrid.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!--jQuery Bootgrid-->
        <div class="container">
            <h1>JQuery Bootgrid</h1>
            <table id="grid-basic" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condensed" data-toggle="bootgrid">
            <thead>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">Group ID</th>
                    <th data-column-id="group_name" data-order="desc">Group Name</th>
                    <th data-column-id="group_desc">Group Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>        
            <tbody>
            @foreach(var xrow in selectedData){
                <tr>
                    <td>@xrow.GroupID</td>
                    <td>@xrow.GroupName</td>
                    <td>@xrow.GroupDesc</td>
                </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
</body>`
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Many thanks

Comment: did u notice any `console errors`??

Comment: Hi. No errors that I could see no.

Comment: Sorry I hit enter in this comment box all the time then the post submits ... Aaaargh

Comment: OK I figured it out.  The bootgrid website says that you can initiate the grid functionality with either javascript or via attributes in the tags.  In my post above, I use the tag attributes route which doesn't work.  Before I posted I also tried with javascript and obviously it didn't work but my javascript had one fault in.  See required below.

Comment: I added this JS to the html <HEAD>.            <script>
            function testBtn() {
                alert("Start prettify");
                $("#tb1").bootgrid();
                alert("end prettify");
            }
        </script>
    </head>.   VERY IMPORTANT to notice:  In HTML, my table has an id tag with value "tb1".   In the javascript, I pass "#tb1" to the bootgrid function.  I don't understand this at all, but that was my problem.

Comment: which `js`?? I don't think adding `js` to html head creates any problem other than problem w.r.t performance!!

Comment: I needed this JS in the HEAD:    <script> $("#tb1").bootgrid();  </script>.

Comment: Ok.. I think you haven't seen my answer though I posted it before!! :) Anyways!! Gald you got it.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing this

`$("#grid-basic").bootgrid();`

Have you written this anywhere in your `js` file???

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  That JS need to be added to the HTML HEAD.  And the part that says "#grid-basic" means that your html table must have an ID tag of "grid-basic" (without the #).  In my example, I called the table "tb1" in the html table tag and therefore my javarscript line looks like: $("#tb1").bootgrid();

Comment: But if you see your question you have given `grid-basic` as `table id` and so the above answer goes matching!! Anyhow you just changed to whatever you have implemented!! That's ok.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The bootgrid functionality must be activated using Javascript called on the HTML page.  Full page code below:  Note my HTML table called "tb1" and the javascript line in the HEAD that calls bootgrid function but passed through a value of "#tb1".

```
@{
    var db = Database.OpenConnectionString("server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=BlueprintManager;trusted_connection=True", "System.Data.SqlClient");
    var selectedData = db.Query("SELECT * FROM tbBPGroups");
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>My Site's Title</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery.bootgrid.min.css">
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.bootgrid.js"></script>

        <script>
            function testBtn() {
                alert("Start prettify");
                $("#tb1").bootgrid();
                alert("end prettify");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!--jQuery Bootgrid-->
        <div class="container">
            <h1>JQuery Bootgrid</h1>
            <table id="tb1" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr class="active">
                    <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">Group ID</th>
                    <th data-column-id="group_name" data-order="desc">Group Name</th>
                    <th data-column-id="group_desc">Group Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>        
            <tbody>
            @foreach(var xrow in selectedData){
                <tr>
                    <td>@xrow.GroupID</td>
                    <td>@xrow.GroupName</td>
                    <td>@xrow.GroupDesc</td>
                </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <br>
        <br>

        <Button id="init-basic" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="testBtn();">
            Activate Bootgrid Now >>>
        </button>
     </div>

    </body>
</html>
```